# How to easy configure Hadoop for big MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm doing my student work. Please help me understand in what direction should I move.

So, I have a big MySQL database (31.3Gb, 130 millions rows) on my PC. I have written a simple html page (interface for my program). I'm using PHP for connecting to my database, AJAX for retrieve data from a server asynchronously and OpenServer (local server for testing).

How it works: the user selects some filters on my html page, clicks the search button, and it displays the main table.

Everything works well, but what should I use to connect my project to Hadoop? It is a mandatory requirement.
Maybe HortonWorks/Cloudera/Docker?
It will be very useful if you send links on some useful guides.

The main criterion is simple to configure and install. Also, I have only 4Gb of RAM on my laptop, so most likely I have to use old versions of tools. HortonWorks 2.1 was successfully installed even on my virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.04)
In advance thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: What do you plan to do with Hadoop?

Comment: Use to speed up the search from the table. To be honest, I did not understand much about it. It is only necessary for my university homework

Comment: Will give some pointers in the answer, since it may not be clear here in the comments section. Hope it gets you going.

Comment: You don't "configure Hadoop for MySQL"... You would "export the database" **into Hadoop**... But, it's not clear why you need that. It definitely won't speed things up with that little of memory you have... You need a **database** (like HBase), not the Hadoop FileSystem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sqoop import](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal) to push data from MySQL to [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive).
Then, you can query via [HiveServer2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2).

For getting Hadoop and other components, it is best to use [HDP](https://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/) or [CDH](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-13.html) sandbox. If your machine resources do not permit using the sandbox, consider using [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/).

Once you have data in Hive, you can point your application to query Hive and serve results, instead of going to MySQL.